# How to copy values of a Component from object A to the same Component on object B?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make inventory loader, but I don't know I could set component to older component. Of course I would make it with set every variable, but that doesn't have sense for me, because I think that can be done a lot easier.

I have 2 GameObjects with the same components. While I'm loading my second player I want to declare there the same variables as the old GameObject ("Local Player"). I want to make it for network, because one Player Prefab is Network Player and second one is Local Player, for not online lobbies.

The script is on the new Player, which spawn while Player join to server.

```
gameObject.GetComponent<Inventory>() = GameObject.Find("Local Player").GetComponent<Inventory>();
```

Error: The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable, property or indexer

Thanks!

Comment: Can you tell me what problem you are facing right now, because for me it wasn't clear enough from your question alone?

Comment: Left Site must be the variable for change it.

Comment: @Pretzel I think that what Mathew try to say is that your question description, doesn't have a question, or at least is not easy to say what is your problem, what are you trying to achieve and why it doesn't work ^^ (or at least it doesn't say it in a way that Mathew and I can understand :( )

Comment: Ok, I will try to change it for less confusing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetComponent<Inventory>()` **returns** a **reference** ... you cant assign a value to it ... what you are trying to do is probably deep cloning the component with all its current values.

---

#### General case

There seems to be a solution for this (didn't test it though) from [this thread](https://answers.unity.com/questions/530178/how-to-get-a-component-from-an-object-and-add-it-t.html) using Reflection to deep copy the field and property values of one component to another. Only refactored it slightly ;)

> So I finally found a solution to copying components at runtime - via
> reflection. Thanks to @Jamora who pointed out that I could set values
> via reflection too, not just get them.
>
> This extension method gets a copy of a component:
>
> ```
> public static class ComponentExtensions
> {
>      public static T GetCopyOf<T>(this T comp, T other) where T : Component
>      {
>          Type type = comp.GetType();
>          Type othersType = other.GetType();
>          if (type != othersType)
>          {
>              Debug.LogError($"The type \"{type.AssemblyQualifiedName}\" of \"{comp}\" does not match the type \"{othersType.AssemblyQualifiedName}\" of \"{other}\"!");
>              return null;
>          }
>
>          BindingFlags flags = BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Default;
>          PropertyInfo[] pinfos = type.GetProperties(flags);
>
>          foreach (var pinfo in pinfos) 
>          {
>              if (pinfo.CanWrite) 
>              {
>                  try 
>                  {
>                      pinfo.SetValue(comp, pinfo.GetValue(other, null), null);
>                  }
>                  catch
>                  {
>                      /*
>                       * In case of NotImplementedException being thrown.
>                       * For some reason specifying that exception didn't seem to catch it,
>                       * so I didn't catch anything specific.
>                       */
>                  }
>              }
>          }
>
>          FieldInfo[] finfos = type.GetFields(flags);
>
>          foreach (var finfo in finfos) 
>          {
>              finfo.SetValue(comp, finfo.GetValue(other));
>          }
>          return comp as T;
>      }
> }
> ```
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
>  var copy = myComp.GetCopyOf(someOtherComponent);
> ```
>
> To make things more convenient, I added this GameObject extension
> method to add a component directly by just passing it so a copy of it
> will get added:
>
> ```
>  public static T AddComponent<T>(this GameObject go, T toAdd) where T : Component
>  {
>      return go.AddComponent<T>().GetCopyOf(toAdd) as T;
>  }
> ```
>
> Usage:
>
> ```
>  Health myHealth = gameObject.AddComponent<Health>(enemy.health);
> ```

---

#### Specific Component

In general however I think you wouldn't use this just on any component but should rather simply implement such functionality directly in your component and do e.g. something like

```
public class MyComponent : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int someIntField;
    private string someStringProperty { get; private set; }
    public GameObject someReference;
    // ...

    public void CopyValuesFrom(MyComponent input)
    {
        // Since you are in the same class you have access to all private members ;)
        someIntField = input.someIntField;
        someStringProperty = input.someStringProperty;
        someReference = input.someReference;
        // ...
    }
}
```

and then do e.g.

```
objectB.GetComponent<MyComponent>().CopyValuesFrom(objectA.GetComponnet<MyComponent>());
```

That would be the cleaner solution.

---

**Careful though!!**

For both solutions especially for reference types like e.g. `List<T>` or your custom classes etc. you might rather want to create deep clones instead of just copying the reference e.g.

```
private List<string> someList;

...

someList = new List<string>(input.someList);
```

Comment: That is great solution, but I think is minimally complicated. Thanks anyway! I will try to understand it, because that looks more profesionally haha.

Comment: @Pretzel see the update at the bottom for an in my eyes way cleaner solution ;)